# Android: How to get id of the spinner item using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

My spinner is loaded with  some messages ,each message has itz own id,

```
public class Message {
    private String id;
    private String message;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

     @Override
     public String toString() {          
         return  message;
     }
}
```

I am passing this `message` to Arrayadapter,

```
   protected List<Message> messages = null;
    ArrayAdapter <Message> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>( activity,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,messages);               
                        arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview);
 spinner1.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
```

Now how can i get the id of that particular message selected? 
can i do it with arrayadapter .Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post some your xml also?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            Message mSelected = (Message) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            Log.i("Id:", mSelected.getId());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Message", "Nothing is selected");

        }


    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot Message mSelected = (Message) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos); is exactly what i want ..thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You should set on item click listener on spinner:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```