# How can I replicate select (HTML) in android string.xml file

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, arrays

I have to replicate

```
<select>
  <option value="36">Volvo</option>
  <option value="45">Saab</option>
  <option value="56">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="71">Audi</option>
</select>
```

in `string.xml` so that when I select any Item in `Spinner` it gives me value of the item instead of name of the item.
I mean I have to use this value. I tried using `StringArray` but it does not give me option to give value to an item. A the values are static I was wondering if this can be done in string.xml rather than using other workarounds.

Please tell me how can I proceed.

Comment: Read question and answer for complete solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957245/android-how-to-get-id-of-the-spinner-item-using-arrayadapter

Comment: Thanks got my answer from [here](http://www.katr.com/article_android_spinner01.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can define two string-arrays, one for the names, another for the values :

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:entries="@array/array_names"
    android:entryValues="@array/array_name_values"
/>
```

EDIT :

Forgot strings.xml

strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="array_names">
    <item>Volvo</item>
    <item>Saab</item>
    <item>Mercedes</item>
    <item>Audi</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="array_name_values">
    <item>36</item>
    <item>45</item>
    <item>56</item>
    <item>71</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spinners and other similar list-based elements in android are populated via adapters, which translate data (in this case, either an array of data, or a cursor from a database query) into a form that can be displayed by the View.

Here, you want to be looking at an ArrayAdapter; this class is the interface between your data and your spinner. The ArrayAdapter can be populated from a number of sources: An array created programmatically in your java code, or one that is hard-coded as an array in your xml resources string file, like so:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="cars_array">
        <item>Volvo</item>
        <item>Saab</item>
        <item>Mercedes</item>
        <item>Audi</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

If you want to use static data in this way, the 'item' tag does not have any attributes like the options tag in your example does. Your options would be one of the following:

1 - Use this array along with an existing adapter class and put the values in programmatically somewhere in your java code.

2 - Put the values in a separate array resource and create your own adapter class if necessary to use both of them as you wish

For more information and further links on the use of spinners, look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

Hope this helps!